# C#/ Задержка при передаче данных из процедуры в контроллер

Tags: c#, веб-программирование

Столкнулся со странным.  Имеется контроллер:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string id)
{
    MyData md = new MyData();
    //point1
    md = await predata.GetMyData();
    //point2
    return View("index.cshtml", md);
}
```

Сама процедура `GetMyData` выполняется за 10 - 30 миллисекунд. Однако, время между точками `point1` и `point2` колеблется в пределах 12 - 15 секунд.
С чем может быть связано?

Comment: С чем угодно может быть связано. Как вы измерили время в обоих случаях? Может, у вас с измерениями проблема?

Comment: Ну может у вас там есть какие-то более важные процессы, до обработки этой процедуры "руки не доходят"? Попробуйте логи писать, или вы по логам время и меряете?

Comment: Кстати, а зачем вы создаете лишний `new MyData();`? можно убрать первую строчку и написать сразу `MyData md = await predata.GetMyData();`. По поводу лагов, надо смотреть, чем у вас сервер занят. Смотреть загрузку процессора, может он перегружен.